# How to show your homepage on www.example.com rather than /Index.html

Tags: web-hosting, url, homepage

How do you configure a site so that when someone is on your home page, they are looking at `www.example.com`, rather than `www.example.com/Index.html`?   I would like it to show the way that Google's homepage does.

Is it possible with a simple HTML site running on shared hosting with FTP access?

Comment: Assuming Apache? (Although, `Index.html` with a capital `I` ...?)

Comment: @w3dk yes, I believe it is apache based (one.com), lowercase i - yes!

Answer (score 1):

if running Apache use following rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/Index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)Index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Minor regex tidy: `^.*/Index\.html` is the same as `/Index\.html` (the `^.*` prefix is not required). The dot should be escaped in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ also.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Evgeniy's answer which handles the situation when the `/index.html` URL is inadvertently exposed (and indexed) and needs to be canonicalised, you should also ensure that you always link to the bare URL, ie. `/` and not `/index.html`. The end user should never see "`index.html`" anywhere.

For `/` (the bare directory) to work (to silently request `index.html`) you need to ensure that mod_dir is enabled (it is be default) and that the `DirectoryIndex` is set appropriately (default is `index.html`). For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

The `DirectoryIndex` directive tells Apache which file to serve when a filesystem directory (eg. `example.com/` or `example.com/directory/`, etc.) has been requested. In this case it will look for `index.html` and if not found will check for `index.php`, etc. in the respective directory.

To also help the search engines to always index (or at least, return in the SERPs) the correct/canonical URL you can include a `rel="canonical"` element in the `head` section of your pages pointing to the correct URL. For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/">
```

And lastly, setup an external redirect to correct any `index.html` URLs that have already been indexed. (See Evgeniy's answer.)